# WPF - Listview with button

Tags: wpf, listview, button

I have a ListView template, and one column is a button. I need the selected item when I click on this button. How can I do this?

Comment: Do you mean you want to get the currently selected item or do you want to select the item where the button is in?

Answer (score 16):

To cature the selected ListView item inside a button pressed event you can leverage the MVVM pattern. In my ListView, in the XAML, I bind the ItemsSource and SelectedItem to a ViewModel class. I also bind my button Command in the template to RunCommand in the ViewModel.

The tricky part is getting the binding correct from the template to the active DataContext.

Once you do this you can capture the SelectedCustomer inside the RunCommand that 
gets executed when the button gets pressed.

I've included some of the code to help get you started.
You can find implementations of ViewModelBase and DelegateCommand via Google.

Here is the XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="ListViewScrollPosition.Views.MainView"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  Title="Main Window" Height="400" Width="400">
  <Grid>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Customers}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedCustomer}"
              Width="Auto">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="First Name">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Margin="6,2,6,2">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Last Name">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Margin="6,2,6,2">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Address">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Margin="6,2,6,2">
                                <Button Content="Address" 
                                   Command="{Binding 
                                   Path=DataContext.RunCommand, 
                                   RelativeSource=
                                   {RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                                   AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

Here is the ViewModel:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows.Input;
using ListViewScrollPosition.Commands;
using ListViewScrollPosition.Models;

namespace ListViewScrollPosition.ViewModels
{
  public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
  {
    public ICommand RunCommand { get; private set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
      RunCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(OnRunCommand, CanRunCommand);
      _customers = Customer.GetSampleCustomerList();
      _selectedCustomer = _customers[0];
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Customer> _customers = 
                    new ObservableCollection<Customer>();
    public ObservableCollection<Customer> Customers
    {
      get
      {
        return _customers;
      }
    }

    private Customer _selectedCustomer;
    public Customer SelectedCustomer
    {
      get
      {
        return _selectedCustomer;
      }
      set
      {
        _selectedCustomer = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedCustomer");
      }
    }

    private void OnRunCommand(object obj)
    {
      // use the SelectedCustomer object here...
    }

    private bool CanRunCommand(object obj)
    {
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

Here is where I link in the ViewModel to the View:

```
public partial class MainView : Window
{
  public MainView()
  {
     InitializeComponent();
     DataContext = new ViewModels.MainViewModel();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Example with a regular click event in the code behind:

```
<ListView Height="167.96" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding FulfillmentSchedules}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedFulfillmentSchedule}">
  <ListView.View>
    <GridView>
      <GridViewColumn Header="Request">
        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock>
              <TextBlock.Text>
                <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}-{1}-{2}">
                  <Binding Path="Template.ProjectNumber" />
                  <Binding Path="Template.JobNumber" />
                  <Binding Path="Template.RequestId" />
                </MultiBinding>
              </TextBlock.Text>
            </TextBlock>
          </DataTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>

      </GridViewColumn>
      <GridViewColumn Header="Template" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Template.Name}"/>
      <GridViewColumn Header="Start Date" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding StartDate}"/>
      <GridViewColumn Header="Records" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Parameters.Records}"/>
      <GridViewColumn>
        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <Button Name="BtnYourButton" Content="Your Button" Click="BtnYourButton_Click" />
          </DataTemplate>

        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>

      </GridViewColumn>
    </GridView>
  </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Code behind:

```
private void BtnYourButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  var boundData= (YourBoundDataType)((Button)sender).DataContext;
  //do what you need to do here, including calling other methods on your VM
}
```

Note: While I certainly appreciate MVVM, I've come to accept that there is a pretty steep slope of dimminishing returns once you cross into actions and messaging between the form and the VM, so I use it only in cases of complex relationships between VMs or large singular VMs.  For CRUD style data-centric applications I prefer to handle actions and message relay with the code behind.