# Button inside a WPF List view/data grid

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light, wpfdatagrid

I am trying to get the value/ID of the clicked row. If the row is selected, this works fine. But if I just try to click the button inside, the selected customer is null. How do I do Command Parameters here.
I tried this see the answers to the following questions:

[ListView and Buttons inside ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3045872/listview-and-buttons-inside-listview)

[WPF - Listview with button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4921046/wpf-listview-with-button)

Here is the code:

```
<Grid>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Customers}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedCustomer}"
          Width="Auto">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="First Name">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Margin="6,2,6,2">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Address">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Margin="6,2,6,2">
                                <Button Content="Address" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.RunCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>

</Grid>

public class VM : ViewModelBase
{
    public RelayCommand RunCommand { get; private set; }
    private ObservableCollection<Customer> _Customers;
    public ObservableCollection<Customer> Customers
    {
        get { return _Customers; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _Customers)
            {
                _Customers = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Customers");
            }
        }
    }

    private Customer _SelectedCustomer;
    public Customer SelectedCustomer
    {
        get { return _SelectedCustomer; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _SelectedCustomer)
            {
                _SelectedCustomer = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedCustomer");
            }
        }
    }

    public VM()
    {
        Customers = Customer.GetCustomers();
        RunCommand = new RelayCommand(OnRun);
    }

    private void OnRun()
    {
        Customer s = SelectedCustomer;
    }
}
```

in the OnRun Method, selected Customer is coming in as null. I want the data row(customer) here. How do I do this?

Comment: So if the row is selected and then you click the button it works? Have you tried automatically selecting the row the button is clicked from?

Comment: What do you mean by that? How do you automatically select the row? The user selects it. I am confused

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Three possible solutions that you can choose.

- Pass current row object as a CommandParameter. In this case, you will modify OnRun method a little. (recommended)

`<Button Content="Address" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.RunCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" CommandParameter={Binding} />`

I think **CommandParameter={Binding}** works fine because the DataContext of each row is each Customer object.

and OnRun method needs to be modified in order to get a parameter as an argument.

```
    private void OnRun(object o){
        if(!(o is Customer)) return;
        // Do something
    }
```

- Or, Write a little code-behind with SelectionChanged event handling. (not recommended)
- Or, Use EventToCommand in MVVM-light toolkit. (not recommended)

Answer (score 0):

CommandParameter does NOT entirely support data binding.

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/472932/wpf-commandparameter-binding-should-be-evaluated-before-command-binding