# How do you bind a Button Command to a member method?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, data-binding, mvvm

I have a ListView in my MVVM WPF implementation, it has a DataTemplate with a button inside.  The ListView is bound to a collection of complex objects in the ViewModel.

```
 <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ComplexObjects}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedObject}"
          Width="Auto">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="My Property">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Margin="6,2,6,2">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyProperty}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Header="First Name">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Margin="6,2,6,2">
                            <Button Command="{Binding ???}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
    </GridView>
</ListView.View>
```

All the text fields are bound with no problem, but can I bind the Button Command to a member method of the ComplexObject?  If so is there any way to pass parameters?

I have a feeling I'm probably just evading using an ICommand.

Thanks.

Comment: @DJ KRAZE - I'm not sure how that would help - I'm looking to bind to the complex object, not the code behind.

Comment: here is something that might help then If I understand correctly Button in that since doesn't truly support Binding but this site may help clarify http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/472932/wpf-commandparameter-binding-should-be-evaluated-before-command-binding | here is a similar post on StackOverFlow that will give you 3 possible options as well http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/472932/wpf-commandparameter-binding-should-be-evaluated-before-command-binding

Comment: @DJ KRAZE Thanks, but same link posted twice there.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882125/button-inside-a-wpf-list-view-data-grid Sorry.. Dang Copy Paste..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could bind an `ICommand` on the ViewModel, passing the instance to invoke the method on as a parameter. The ViewModel can then call the appropriate method on the right `ComplexObject`.

For example:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel Margin="6,2,6,2">
        <Button Command="{Binding DoSomethingCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ViewModelType}, Mode=FindAncestor}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Then the viewmodel could look like so:

```
public ICommand DoSomethingCommand
{
    get { return new DelegateCommand<object>(DoSomething); }
}

private void DoSomething(object instance)
{
    var complexObject = instance as ComplexObject;
    if (complexObject != null)
        complexObject.SomeMethod();
}
```

Comment: Like the answer, I cannot get the binding to work at this point

Comment: Got it, but Im not using RelativeSource just {Binding ElementName=nameOfListView, Path=DataContext.DoSomethingCommand}

Comment: Answer could also use some explanation around DelegateCommand, I have used them before, but others may not have.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad you got it working, your solution is probably more efficient than traversing the tree too.

Answer (score 2):

If you really wanted to get crazy I suppose you could make your own button custom control with a dependency property that is a `delegate`, and you could then bind to a property that returns the same type of `delegate`. And then in your custom control class you could invoke the delegate when it gets clicked.

---

There is always the standard ICommand, if you go that route this is how...

```
<Button Command={Binding CommandProperty} />
```

Use Kent Boogaart's DelegateCommand class from his [blog post](http://kentb.blogspot.com/2009/04/mvvm-infrastructure-delegatecommand.html).
Then...

In the class you are binding to:

```
private ICommand _commandField;

public ICommand CommandProperty
{
  get
  {
    if (_commandField == null) _commandField = new DelegateCommand(CommandMethod);

    return _commandField;
  }
}

private void CommandMethod() 
{
  // do stuff...
}
```

Comment: I think the asker is trying to avoid using an `ICommand` on each `ComplexObject` and is looking for a way to directly invoke a method.

Answer (score 0):

Yes for Button you will need to use ICommand established in your ComplexObject:

```
<Button Command="{Binding Path = CommandName}"/>
```

If your method is in the View Model that holds the ComplexObjects collection name your control or window **Me** and use something like this:

```
<Button Command="{Binding ElementName=Me, Path=DataContext.CommandName}" />
```

You could use click or preview mouse down, but if you're wanting to bind the method in XAML, you would still need to route that event to a command.  It's just easier to bind the command.